# Display custom template file in Magento 2.2

Tags: template, magento2.2, php-7

I want create a template file for **sales->order->create new order**.

**In layout file(Xxx/Order/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="billing_method">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Xxx_Order::order/create/billing/method/form.phtml" name="order_create_billing_form" as="form" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

This is my core file **Sales-module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Billing\Method" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/abstract.phtml" name="billing_method">
                            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Billing\Method\Form" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/billing/method/form.phtml" name="order_create_billing_form" as="form"/>
                        </block>rm" as="form"/>
                        </block>
```

**form.phtml:**

```
<div class="admin__field">
    <label for="history_comment" class="admin__field-label">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ __('Additional Comment') ?>

    </label>

    <div class="admin__field-control">
        <textarea  rows="3"
                   cols="5"
                   id="order-comment"
                   name="order[order_comment]"
                   class="admin__control-textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

My template file isn't showing after reloading page.

Comment: What is the full file path to sales_order_create_index.xml and additionally to your form.phtml file?

Comment: @Rob updated my post..

Comment: Is the site in developer mode?   If not, you will need to run php/bin magento static:content:deploy. After this is working modifications should be made in a module as you should never update core files directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your xml as below way,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_create_billing_form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Xxx_Order::order/create/billing/method/form.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear cache and check.